# -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overwrite

Tags: html, css

i have a problem that i couldnt find a solution for it. I use bootstrap on my website and it uses

```
*, *:before, *:after {
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

for all buttons.

Now i just installed arrowchat scrip and i have a problem with this rule from above, it ruins my css from arrowchat. I tryed to add

```
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box !important;
```

to my arrowchat class but still it doesnt affect with anything. Can someone give me a solution for this?

Comment: how about making fiddle??? so every one catch it easily.

Comment: Can you give us the links or create a fiddle with the arrowchat script?

Comment: i would give u link but u need to autentificate to see it...

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* Android ≤ 2.3, iOS ≤ 4 */
-moz-box-sizing: content-box; /* Firefox 1+ */
box-sizing: content-box; /* Chrome, IE 8+, Opera, Safari 5.1 */
```

You need all of them to cover all the browsers